# How is possible that those shapes are equivalent in topology?

Tags: general-topology

I recently started to study topology, I have no idea about the subject so my question could be very simple but I need a clear explanation.  It is about the page number 19 of *Introducton to Topology* by Colin Adams and Robert Franzosa; it said that the shapes:

[image: donut]

[image: sphere with two holes]

are equivalent in topology, but one has just one hole and the other has two. is possible to add holes or stick holes?

Comment: Each of the two holes in the sphere has two circular edges. But the first picture also has two circular edges.

Comment: It is important to realize that these examples are NOT two dimensional surfaces, they are three dimensional solids.  Imagine the first solid to be a deflated rubber bag which is then "blown up" to the round second solid.

Comment: The drawing is perhaps not the best but hopefully the others explained it.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Look a bit more closely at the second picture. There's a couple of little dotted lines connecting the two holes that may be a bit hard to see.

[image: (left pic is from post, right pic is super contrast enhanced to tease out line)]

That is meant to convey the impression they are the two ends of a single, long, curved hole through the interior.

Comment: I see the trench, but which one is the superlaser and which one is the exhaust port?

Answer (score 38):

The "two holes" in that sphere are two ends of the same hole. (That is, if you drilled one hole all the way through a sphere, you would end up with something that looked very much like your picture.)

Comment: Or you inflated the flattened donut, which happens to have a weak, more redundant part.

Comment: It’s probably worth noting that in topology a “hole” is not a hole unless it creates an opening that passes entirely through the shape. What we might call a hole... in a wall for instance, after drilling a hole for a screw or something... is not actually a hole in topology.

Answer (score 20):

You may also notice the tunel,  which I agree with you it is not clear in this photo.

Comment: I think this answer captures the real problem, namely that, in the second picture, the tube inside the sphere, which connects the two holes, is represented by a pair of dashed lines that are so faint as to be almost invisible.

Comment: @AndreasBlass, thanks for the comment, that way I managed to receive the "nice answer" badge. +1 from me too.

Answer (score 5):

[image]
The cuboid and the sphere are topological euvivalent. Drill a hole through each body as indicated by the arrow. The resulting bodies are still topological equivalent.